# Rendering entity reference field in the current language

Tags: entities

I need to render an entity reference (taxonomy) field in the current language (not 'en'). I wrote the following code but the result is always in english (all referenced terms are well translated).

```
 
$entity_type = 'node';

$entity_id = 10 //

$source = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($entity_id);

$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
if($language != 'en' && $source->hasTranslation($language)){
    $source = $source->getTranslation($language);
}

$viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$output = '';
if (is_object($source) && $source->hasField($field_name) && $source->access('view')) {
    $value = $source->get($field_name);
    $output = $viewBuilder->viewField($value, $viewmode);
    $output['#cache']['tags'] = $source->getCacheTags();
  }

$output = render($output);
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. 
Any idea?

Comment: is `$source` actually translated? (Meaning is the first `if` statement passing or failing?) Can you do some `kint`-ing and narrow down the issue?

Comment: Yes, $source is translated and the if statement is passing.

Comment: viewField (which is the same as ->view() on the field directly) uses the render built of the entity and so it translates the field with the default behavior, this is the entity language and if the entity is not translatable the current language. So the code looks OK, this is more likely about how you set up translation.

Comment: The $source node is well translated. The entity reference field is not marked as 'user may translate this field'. For translated field (tested with text field i.e.), the code works well. It seems that all referenced items are not rendered with the current language.

Comment: Tried your code on translatable and untranslatable fields, and indeed, I can confirm this is an issue for viewField(). There was a fix [Entity references of untranslatable fields are not displayed in the correct translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2543258), but obviously this didn't cover viewField(), not much used in core and probably has no test coverage.